# Updating datagridview with mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My update textbox is named: updateref
and my data field I am trying to update with the selected column is refid

I am sorry I am a noob and all new to integrating mysql with vb.net, any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

'MYSQL CODE

```
    Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("my info")
    Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim query As String
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        query = "UPDATE exploitsociety SET reffer='" + updateref.Text + "' WHERE reffer='" + DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected + "';"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader

        Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
        End try
        con.Close()
```

Basially I was wanting to just edit the column data in the dataviewgrid then just hit update but it was to complicated so I added a textbox to see if I could do it that way and I couldn't either.

Comment: can you tell what is the exception you are facing or any issue in updating.

Comment: Yes it simply just throws and sql error, this code what I think it does is whatever box you have selected it updates that box in the mysql db with the text box. Am I correct, that is what I am intending it to do.

Comment: can you provide the error details here

Comment: Additional information: Conversion from string "UPDATE exploitsociety SET reffer" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: I did and it threw the same error.

Comment: My column's name is refid
the textbox name is updateref

If this helps at all

Comment: Then replace the reffer to refid, see the updated answer. What is the DataType of refid and reffer?

Comment: only one column and datatype is int

Answer (score 0):

It seems you try update query

```
Dim con As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection("my info")
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader

Try
    con.Open()
    Dim query As String


     Dim command As MySqlCommand
        query = "UPDATE exploitsociety SET reffer='" + updateref.Text + "' WHERE reffer='" + DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected + "';"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
  //      reader = command.ExecuteReader

  //     you need to run ExecuteNonQuery instead of ExecuteReader
      int UpdatedRows=  command.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Dispose()
        End try
    con.Close()
```

Just for your informationn

**ExecuteReader**

Execute Reader will be used to return the set of rows, on execution of SQL Query or Stored procedure using command object. This one is forward only retrieval of records and it is used to read the table values from first to last.(Read More about ExecuteReader)

**ExecuteNonQuery**

ExecuteNonQuery method will return number of rows effected with INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE operations. This ExecuteNonQuery method will be used only for insert, update and delete, Create, and SET statements. ([Read More about ExecuteNonQuery](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/executenonquery-example-in-aspnet-using.html))

Comment: `UpdatedRows`  is nothing it just return count of rows that updated .  so you can make sure your table rows updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what exception (if any) it throws:

```
Using cn = New MySQLConnection("my info")
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd = New MySQLCommand("UPDATE exploitsociety SET reffer='" + updateref.Text + "' WHERE reffer='" + DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected + "'", cn)
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: This also threw the double arrow

Comment: Must be your query, then.

Answer (score 0):

Then Try the following query for updating, remove the single quotes.

```
query = "UPDATE exploitsociety SET refid=" + updateref.Text + " WHERE refid=" + DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected
 command = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
 command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

You can get the selected cells value also as below

```
DataGridView1.SelectedCells[<index of column>].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: @Jake, please tell me the DataType of referr column, and what is the value you are entering in updateref Textbox

Comment: dataype is int and a number in the nextbox, basically just trying to update the highlighted column with what is in the updatered.text

Comment: As you said the column name is refid and the datatype is Int, I have changed the codes accordingly. Refer to the changed answer.

Comment: still throwing the error it has something to do with this: DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected, when I take that out the error goes away