# Updating MYSQL records via VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

What I am trying to do is do the basic insert, refresh and update mysql querys in my vb.net application. The refresh, and the insert work perfect the only one I can't get is the update can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Here is a picture of the program layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0k96.png

and here is my source code:

```
Private Sub KnightButton3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles KnightButton3.Click
    cn = New MySqlConnection
    cn.ConnectionString = "my info"

    Try
        cn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        Dim command As MySqlCommand
        query = "UPDATE Refers.exploitsociety SET Refferals='" + refupdate.Text + "' WHERE Refferals='" + DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected + "';"
        command = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cn.Dispose()
    End Try
    cn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: So show the UPDATE code instead of a SELECT query

Comment: update is button 3 / updated code

Comment: The first thing I would do is put a break point on the "query =" line, then look at the value of DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Selected and make sure that value is actually in the table you want to update.  Also side note, parameterize your query to protect against SQL injection exploits.

Comment: Any example of code? I have probably been on every topic and I just can't get it, I am new to this buddy, thanks for the reply!

Comment: But did you have any error here? Any message in that exception that you would like to share?

Comment: @steve 
     
Additional information: Conversion from string "UPDATE exploitsociety SET reffer" to type 'Double' is not valid.

I have another thread here too his no success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29426103/updating-datagridview-with-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is in the usage of the property [Selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.selected(v=vs.100).aspx) of the CurrentCell. This is a boolean value and it is not the content of that cell.
I would use this kind of code with a parameterized query and a using statement around disposable objects

```
Try
     query = "UPDATE Refers.exploitsociety " & _ 
             "SET Refferals=@refs " & _ 
             "WHERE Refferals=@oldrefs"

    Using cn = New MySqlConnection(".... connection string ....")
    Using command = New MySqlCommand(query, cn)
        cn.Open()
        command.Parameters.Add("@refs", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = _
                               Convert.ToInt32(refupdate.Text)
        command.Parameters.Add("@oldrefs", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = _
                Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.Value.ToString())
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    End Using
Catch ex As MySqlException
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
```

Notice that with a using statement you don't need to close/dispose the connection because this is automatically done when the code leaves the using block (also in case of exceptions)

Comment: can I ask what @refs is? Thank you, Could you also add one that isn't parameterized, cause I don't get that one bit. I am sorry./

Comment: `@refs` and `@oldrefs`  are  placeholders for the parameters. Using this approach you don't need to put quotes around your string and avoid Sql Injection

Comment: Additional information: Connection must be valid and open. I get that when I replace my code with yours

Comment: @Jake I will not give you an answer without a parameters because it is a really wrong thing to do. First [look at this famous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) that explains Sql Injection. String concatenation is dangerous at the extreme. Second, with a string concatenation if your referrals valus contains a single quote the whole code will crash again with a syntax error. Third, your query text now is really simple to understand.

Comment: Additional information: Connection must be valid and open. I get that when I replace my code with yours –

Comment: Of course you set the connection string as before right? My code `....connection string....` is just a markup where you should put the correct details of your connection string. (yours `"my info"` )

Comment: Please view the picture here: http://i.imgur.com/SiFPnG3.png also the Refferals is INT

Comment: Yes lol I set my connection string, I am dumb but not that dumb :D

Comment: Well, excuse me then, only there is no reason to get that error if the MySqlCommand constructor receives both the query string and the connection. Finally if the DataType of Referrals is an integer then the parameter should be of type integer and the value passed to the parameter should be of the same type. I will update the answer

Comment: I get this error: Additional information: Connection must be valid and open.

Comment: Okay so that worked! (kinda) This changed every cell to 20 of the Refferals column

Comment: NVM SIR IT WORKED! Thank you so much. I checked this answer, can you explain this code if not that is fine

Comment: Some links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468425/how-do-parameterized-queries-help-against-sql-injection http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.shtml https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/